# How to teach WebStorm to recognize dynamic import statement?

Tags: reactjs, webstorm, babeljs

When I'm trying to use dynamic import statement in WebStorm I receive a syntax error:

[image: screenshot]

How to solve a problem?

**P.S.** JSX mode is on, everything is okey. I feel it's expecting a static import statement like `import Login from '...'`, but I need dynamic - `import(...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This bug is fixed in 2017.3, please try the [EAP](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/WI/WebStorm+EAP)